# How to fix a button so that it does not change its position on effect of its neighbouring elements?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code..

```
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs minus'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span>
</button>

&nbsp;
<span class='quantity bold font20' val='1'>1</span>
&nbsp;

<button class='btn btn-success btn-xs plus'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
</button>
```

On clicking the **Plus Button** the *Quantity Value* increases and on clicking the **Minus Button** *Quantity Value* decreases  !

But as the value increases or decreases the Plus Button shifts right or left...
How can I position it fixed ? So that on increasing the value, the button does not move from its place !

Here's my CSS..

```
.bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}

.font20
{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please also share your css code..

Comment: add width to quantity

Comment: Tried Width.. not worked !

Comment: because it's a span, so you need to make it inline-block befor applying width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Adding width and height in span tag

```css
.quantity {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.font20 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs minus'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span>
</button>

&nbsp;
<span class='quantity bold font20' val='1'>1</span>
&nbsp;

<button class='btn btn-success btn-xs plus'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/1xhmytd4/16/)

You need to `float: left` each `button` and `.quantity` then give `.quantity` width. If number increaces and overflow, the scrollbar will showed.

```css
button,
.quantity {
  float: left
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.font20 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.quantity {
  /* make text  horizontal center */
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* need to display span as block */
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  /*if overflow show scrollbar or you can change to overflow-x: hidden without scrollbar */
  overflow-x: auto;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs minus'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'>-</span>
</button>

<span class='quantity bold font20' val='1'>99999</span>

<button class='btn btn-success btn-xs plus'>
  <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'>+</span>
</button>

<!-- For Clearing float -->
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
```